# Anchor link target style (:target) is not applied on dynamic HTML content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've set a default style in CSS:

```css
:target
    {
        animation-name: flash;
        animation-delay: 600ms;
        animation-duration: 1200ms;
        animation-iteration-count: 2;
    }
```

If I go to my page "mysite.com/mypage" directly from the URL bar or if I refresh the page, then when I click on any anchor link on the page, the above CSS style is applied.

However, when I am on another page of my site and I click on the link to open "mypage", it is loaded in AJAX (so the HTML is dynamically loaded). Then if I click on the same anchor link as previously in that page, the browser view is  correctly moved to the target, BUT the CSS style is not applied.

Why? I've been spending like 2 days to solve this. I'm wondering if there is a bug in CSS or something like that.

PS: I can show the whole code but I feel like it's gonna be confusing (it's not my code and I tried to decipher it for many hours already), looking for a general answer first

Comment: When you load the content via AJAX, are you adjusting `window.location.hash` accordingly?

Comment: Are you saying when "mypage" is loaded via AJAX it fully replaces current page?

Comment: @amdouglas it was loading window.location.pathname but I just replaced by window.location.href (it includes the hash) after you mentioned it, and still same result.

Comment: @vanowm not the whole page, only a big div

Comment: Well, there something else is going on, replacing content of a div should work just finet:
https://jsfiddle.net/mnck8fyd/

Comment: @Barbz_YHOOL if the hash is being updated, I suspect it's a problem of CSS specificity, i.e. whatever rules you have for `#mydiv:target` are being overriden by something. It's hard to advise without being able to see the thing in action.

Comment: Like @vanowm I'm also not encountering any trouble with `:target` when dynamically changing hash link: https://jsfiddle.net/2o8xfstr/2/ and XHRing some extra content shouldn't interfere with that.

Comment: Thank you @amdouglas, I put a comment on Vanown's answer for my findings. I also found a very hacky solution meanwhile that consists in comparing previous/next url and hash but it's dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add hash into location AFTER new elements were added into DOM:

```js
var i = 0;
function addDiv(locationFirst)
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "test" + i++;
  div.textContent = div.id;
  if (locationFirst)
  {
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    window.location.replace("#" + div.id);
  }
  else
  {
    window.location.replace("#" + div.id);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

```css
div
{
    display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3em;
    margin: 0.1em;
}
:target
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="addDiv()">click me. url hash first = :target not applied</div>
<div onclick="addDiv(1)">click me. url hash last = :target applied</div>
```

Comment: Ok, you are right the hash is not updated AFTER the ajax call, it's instead directly put in the url (dunno how to explain). In fact, it correctly targets the (old) element but immediately after the html is replaced by the new content. I put a settimeOut to try and I could see it live. So if I try to "update" the hash, it has already been triggered. How can I retrigger it if the hash is already present in the URL?

Comment: Note that thanks to you and @amdouglas I found two different solutions to my problem, the only issue remaining is the thing i posted above, to "retrigger" the hash, why? it's only when going backward/forward in the history from a new page to a previous page WITH a #hash, in that case I need to refresh the hash after the AJAX call

Comment: What you can do is use event.preventDefault() in onclick function, so the hash is not added into URL right the way, and than add it once ajax is finished.

Comment: yeah but then can't trigger the ":target" CSS pseudo-class effect :(

Comment: ok finally it works, to retrigger it use `window.location.replace(hash);`, what i did is a bit dirty in some places but it's totally unnoticeable for the user experience, everything works fine. Thanks for the help